# Number of simple paths in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, eulerian-path

I intend a *simple path* to be a path in a graph in which an element does not appear twice.

Now, let $ G = \langle V,E\rangle $ be a graph.

My professor told us that the maximum number of simple paths in a graph is
$$\sum_{i}^{|V|}(i!)$$
Where $i$ denotes the length of the path.

I would say it's not like this. If $|V| = 1000$ and $i=3$ seems I can create only 6 simple paths when the length of it is 3, which I don't think it's the case.

I think the exact formula would be
$$\sum_{i=0}^{|V|}\frac{|V|!}{(|V|-i)!}$$
Which sums the number of *k-permutations of n* for each length of the path. Am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Do you count path $a-b-c$ to be the same as $c-b-a$?

Comment: @Aqua you're right, I forgot the "!", fixed it

Comment: Won't it depend upon the structure of the graph $G$, i.e., how are the vertices connected etc.?

Comment: @sandipan-dey right, I was thinking about  "the maximum number of simple paths  in a graph" but didn't specify it. Thank you for have pointed it out